# Suppose that $a\in \mathbb{C}$ is algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$ with $p(x) =$ min$(\mathbb{Q}, a)$, and let $b$ be any root in $\mathbb{C}$ of $p$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

**Suppose that $a\in \mathbb{C}$ is algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$ with $p(x) =$ min$(\mathbb{Q}, a)$, and let $b$ be any root in $\mathbb{C}$ of $p$. Show that the map $\sigma:\mathbb{Q}(a)\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ given
by $\sigma(f (a)) = f (b)$ is a well-defined $\mathbb{Q}-$homomorphism.**

I have a question about how are the elements of $\mathbb{Q}(a)$, are polynomials in $\mathbb{Q}$ evaluated in $a$? if this is so I would do the following: To see good definition take $f(a), g(a)\in\mathbb{Q}(a)$ with $f(a)=g(a)$ then $\sigma(f(a))=f(b)$ and $\sigma(g(a))=g(b)$  how can I conclude that $f(b)=g(b)$? To see what is a $\mathbb{Q}-$homomorphism: $\sigma(f(a)+g(a))=\sigma((f+g)(a))=(f+g)(b)=f(b)+g(b)$ is and also $\sigma(f(a)g(a))=\sigma((fg)(a))=(fg)(b)=f(b)g(b)$. Is this all good that I have done? Thank you very much.

Comment: $\mathbb{Q}[x] \longrightarrow \mathbb{Q}(a), f(x) \mapsto f(a)$ is a sujective map with kernel $(p(x))$.

Comment: Just to make sure: do you understand the equality $\mathbb Q(a)=\mathbb Q[a]$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathbb{Q}[x] \longrightarrow \mathbb{Q}(a), f(x) \mapsto f(a)$ is a sujective map with kernel $(p(x))$. If the degree of $p(x)$ is $n$, then for every element of $\overline{g(x)} \in \mathbb{Q}[x]/(p(x))$ there is a *unique* polynomial $g_0(x) \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ of degree at most $n-1$ such that $\overline{g(x)}=\overline{g_0(x)}$.

Now using the above observation, we can replace $f(a), g(a)$ by $f_0(a), g_0(a)$ where $f_0(x), g_0(x)$ are unique polynomials representing $f$ and $g$ respectively. This gives the well-defineness.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The ring homomorphism $\alpha\colon\mathbb{Q}[x]\to\mathbb{Q}(a)$ such that $\alpha(x)=a$ is a surjective homomorphism, with kernel $I=(f(x))$, the ideal generated by $f(x)$. Therefore $\alpha$ induces an isomorphism $\bar{\alpha}\colon\mathbb{Q}[x]/I\to\mathbb{Q}(a)$.

What about $b$?